# Is there a measure on $\mathbb{R^3}$ other than volume?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Of course there is the trivial measure where each subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$ have measure zero. But I am asking for a measure $\mu$ for which $\mu(E)=1$ where $E=[0,1]^3$. I thought about the radius, but it is not a measure.

So, does such a measure exist?

Thanks.

Comment: there is uniqueness if you ask for a translation-invariant mesure, but no reason to have it without it...

Comment: See also the [Carathéodory extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carathéodory_extension_theorem) for the case of translation-invariant measures as already mentioned by mookid.

Comment: I'm not sure but the Hausdorff measure might work

Comment: Put $\mu'(U):=\mu(U\cap E)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, for every (Lebesgue measurable) $U\subset\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Otherwise, just define a measure $μ$ by $μ(S) = ∫_S f dλ$ where $λ$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and $f \colon ℝ^3 → ℝ_{≥ 0}$ is any measurable function such that $∫_E f dλ = 1$. This gives a lot of measures. (Setting $f = 1_E$ gives the example by ABC.)

Comment: Or $\mu'(U):=\mu(U)/\mu(E)$, where $\mu$ is any measure with $\mu(E)\neq0,\infty$.